# Looking for a closed-form solution for a special ratio

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for ratio $\frac{(1)}{(2)}$ of:

(1) the length of the arc connecting the two intersections of an equilateral hyperbola with its latus rectum to

(2) the semilatus rectum.

If we have the top half of an equilateral hyperbola $$ \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1 \rightarrow \boxed{y = \sqrt{a^{2}+(\frac{ax}{b})^{2}}} $$ and we know that the focal point is at $ (x,y) = (0,\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}) $, the intersections are at $$ a^{2}+b^{2} = a^{2}+\frac{a^{2}x^{2}}{b^2} \rightarrow x = \pm \frac{b^{2}}{a} \rightarrow (x,y)=(\pm \frac{b^2}{a},\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}) $$ and arc-length will be: $$ \int_{--\frac{b^2}{a}}^{\frac{b^2}{a}} \sqrt{1+ {\frac{dy}{dx}}^{2}} dx = \int_{--\frac{b^2}{a}}^{\frac{b^2}{a}} \sqrt{1+\frac{a^{2}x^{2}}{b^{2}(b^{2}+x^{2})}} \ dx $$ (I believe the quantity I substituted is $\frac{dy}{dx}^{2}$...?).

Is there acy closed form solution for this integral (and consquequently, the ratio of this arc length to the semilatus rectum)?

Comment: Lot of recta there...

Comment: Wow, I'm realizing now there's a lot of errors in this... But I hope the idea is still there...

Comment: I was just indulging in an immature moment there...

Answer (score 0):

For a hyperbola whose asymptotes are orthogonal, the ratio can be written as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{x=\sqrt{2}-1}^{\sqrt{2}+1} \sqrt{1+x^{-4}} \, dx \approx 2.1993748274784085928\ldots.$$  There is no elementary closed form expression for the integral.

Comment: Incredible! Does anyone know a proof of why there is no elementary closed form solution to this?

Comment: But is there an elementary closed form expression for the number itself? For instance, if you ask the same question of a parabola, you get $ln(1+\sqrt{2}) + \sqrt{2}$. Does some analogous "nice" expression exist here?

Comment: Let's say that a "nice" expression is one which can be represented by performing a finite amount of operations in the set {addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, logarithm} on the set $ \Bbb Q \cup \{e, \pi \}$.